# How do I login with a web crawler/scraper?

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests, urllib, scrape

I want to create a program that will scrape my accounts reading lists for several sites, and add them to my `Safari` reading list. However, I can't just use the normal link to crawl, since it requires login.

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using HTTP GET messages to load HTML pages. In order to login, HTTP POST message with proper credentials (username and password) will help.

Below is an example of an HTTP POST message to log into a social networking website:

```
post_message = ('POST /accounts/login/ / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
                'Host: www.fakebook.com\r\n'
                'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
                'Content-length: ' + contentlength +'\r\n'
                'Origin: http://'+host+'\r\n'
                'User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.1058$
                'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n'
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n'
                'Cookie: csrftoken='+csrftoken+'; sessionid= '+sessionid+'\r\r\n\n')

# Add POST body to header.
post_message += ('username='+username+'&password='+password+'&csrfmiddlewaretoken='+csrftoken+'&next=/fakebook/\r\n\r\n')
```

You will have to extract the *sessionid* and *csrftoken* from the HTML page where you log in to the website.

For more info on HTTP STATUS codes, refer: [http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/][1]